# Is there a way to select the first element from a collection of types

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to know if there is a way use jQuery (in a chaining fashion) to select the following:

```
<div class="panel">
    <input id="first" type="text" />
    <input id="second" type="text" />
</div>

<div class="panel">
    <h2>Panel title</h2>
    <textarea id="third"></textarea>
    <input id="fourth" type="text" />
</div>

<div class="panel">
    <p>Some paragraph</p>
    <select id="fifth"></select>
    <input id="sixth" type="text" />
</div>
```

I would like to select the first form element (i.e. either `input`/`select`/`textarea`) that exist in each `div.panel`.

So in the above example, my jQuery selector would return a collection of three elements: `input#first`, `textarea#third` and `select#fifth`.

The following loop will get me the results that I am after, but surely there is a cleaner way in line with jQuery that can do this in one go?

```
var firstFormFieldList = [];

$('.panel').each(function(i, el){
   var firstEl = $(el).find('input,select,textarea').filter(':first');
   firstFormFieldList.push(firstEl);
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the `:input` selector ([DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)):

```
$('.panel').find(':input:first')
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5FQ3T/)

Comment: will that select <select> and <textarea>?

Comment: See link to DOCS, and Example.

Comment: That's the perfect solution. Thanks. Out of interest, what would the solution be if we needed to select the first element from types: h2, h3 and p. Is the solution creating a custom jQuery selector?

Comment: You could also shorten it by doing: `$(':input:first', '.panel')`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector).

```
$('.panel').find(':input:first')
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/cfrVc/).

You must split up the selector, otherwise it will only find the first input element, not the first of each.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
$('.panel').each(function(){
    alert($(this).children(':input').first().attr('id'));
});
```

Check & play with it here - http://jsfiddle.net/dhruvasagar/yLnnX/